# Add code snippet with multiple availability scopes? Xcode 13

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, code-snippets, xcode13

How do you update Xcode 13 code snippets so they are available in more than one scope? For example, update a code snippet to `Availability: Class Implementation or Top level`.

It seems this should be possible because I see that some of the default Swift code snippets are available in more than one scope, but I don't see any setting to add another scope to my custom ones.

Comment: Can you copy-paste and set scopes for each?

Comment: Hmm I suppose you could, but this is more of a work-around than a solution.

Comment: I would love to be able to make a snippet available for all scopes except inside comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently realized you can just check mark more than one scope. Not sure why I didn't figure this out before

[image]